# how to get images for slider banner from other page in asp.net in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, slider

This code is working fine but how can I give the live url of other page like http://www.abe.com?

This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/landscape"));

        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "img/landscape/" + fileName));
        }

        Repeater1.DataSource = files;
        Repeater1.DataBind();           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of external image urls you can bind them directly in a repeater.  Note, you haven't included your html, so I'm going to assume there's no reason to use a `ListItem`.

Code Behind:

```
  Repeater1.DataSource = new List<string>{ 
       "http://www.abebooks.com/images/Homepage/cover-art/chicago-1.jpg",
       "http://www.abebooks.com/images/Homepage/cover-art/chicago-3.jpg"
     };

  Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Then in your Markup:

```
 <div class="slider container">
      <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <img src="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
 </div>
```